# Can't run my cocos2D game on my iPhone

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

## Solution:

The image wasn't a "real" .png file, I had just changed the extension. I downloaded a png file and now it works!

I've done a simple game with cocos2D and I'm trying to run it on my iphone 5. The icon loads and the laungh image loads but then I get a long message with errors etc. For example that it can't find the file for the images, even though they ARE in the right place and are spelled right.
The game runs perfectly in the simulator and another cocos2D game I downloaded runs fine on my iPhone. I have IOS 7 BETA but it shouldn't matter since the game I downloaded works good in it. 
Does anybody have an idea what it could be?
Thanks in advance!

## EDIT:

Here's the whole error I get in the console:

```
cocos2d: cocos2d-iphone v2.1
cocos2d: compiled with Profiling Support: NO
cocos2d: OS version: 7.0 (0x07000000)
cocos2d: GL_VENDOR:   Imagination Technologies
cocos2d: GL_RENDERER: PowerVR SGX 543
cocos2d: GL_VERSION:  OpenGL ES 2.0 IMGSGX543-95
cocos2d: GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 4096
cocos2d: GL_MAX_TEXTURE_UNITS: 8
cocos2d: GL_MAX_SAMPLES: 4
cocos2d: GL supports PVRTC: YES
cocos2d: GL supports BGRA8888 textures: YES
cocos2d: GL supports NPOT textures: YES
cocos2d: GL supports discard_framebuffer: YES
cocos2d: GL supports shareable VAO: NO
2013-08-16 00:28:34.936 brick jumper[3349:60b] cocos2d: animation started with frame  interval: 60.00
2013-08-16 00:28:34.950 brick jumper[3349:60b] cocos2d: surface size: 1136x640
2013-08-16 00:28:35.001 brick jumper[3349:60b] -[CCFileUtils     fullPathForFilename:resolutionType:] : cocos2d: Warning: File not found: wall.png
2013-08-16 00:28:35.002 brick jumper[3349:60b] cocos2d: Couldn't find file:wall.png
2013-08-16 00:28:35.004 brick jumper[3349:60b] *** Assertion failure in -[HelloWorldLayer addChild:], /Users/tonymichaelsen/Documents/documents/Xcode-projects/brick jumper/brick  jumper/libs/cocos2d/CCNode.m:382
2013-08-16 00:28:35.005 brick jumper[3349:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught  exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Argument must be non-nil'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x2fa944a3 0x39a926c7 0x2fa94375 0x30451c03 0x54c37 0xc8ab5 0x530ad 0xc86f3 0xc98cf   0xb42b5 0xb2ed9 0x55d15 0x3080b 0xaa0b5 0x303e553d 0x3040e4f5 0xaa84f 0xc7b73 0xab009 0xae3fd  0x320c6b2b 0x31d5b893 0x31d5b457 0x31d89f95 0x32163f07 0x32162fa9 0x3216222f 0x322856a9  0x321621f7 0x32285461 0x32123ee7 0x32123b61 0x32123485 0x32119573 0x32115c15 0x32152edd  0xc817f 0x3211a375 0x32119dbb 0x32112ad5 0x320c4a1b 0x320c3d11 0x320c3af9 0x34543bc5  0x345437af 0x2fa5bfdf 0x2fa5bf7b 0x2fa5a737 0x2f9d0d09 0x2f9d0aeb 0x32111791 0x3210d4ad  0xc799b 0x2b08)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cocos2d can't find wall.png.  My guess is you are testing on a retina device.  If so, in your App Delegate, change the line `[sharedFileUtils setEnableFallbackSuffixes:NO];` to `[sharedFileUtils setEnableFallbackSuffixes:YES];`

Alternatively, add higher resolution images (for retina devices) with the extension listed in the App Delegate, ie `wall-ipadhd.png` with 4x resolution (in each dimension).

Comment: I don't thing it possibly can be that because the wall.png is 3888 × 2592 pixels

Comment: Ahh then your problem is most likely the size of wall.png.  The maximum texture size in some devices is 2048x2048.  (You use textures to create sprites in cocos2d.)  The simulator may be able to handle larger textures.  You need to shrink the size of your image.

Comment: To clarify, it's not the resolution of the image that cocos2d cares about for finding the right image.  It's the file name.  You must indicate that an image is for, for example, iPad Retina, by adding the file suffix `-ipadhd`

Comment: So do I have to add the correct suffix everytime the image is in retina resolution? How do I know the image is in that size or resolution?

Answer (score 1):

You say the images are spelled right, but you have *double checked for case*? The simulator will accept incorrectly cased images (ex. the file is named "cocosImage.png" and your code asks for "CocosImage.png") but the device itself will throw an error.

(This is why it's always a good idea to develop on the device itself—you catch these errors right when they happen and have a better idea of where to start from, instead of wondering when it started breaking. :))

Comment: I have checked now again and it's exactly right. Thanks though I keep that in mind